# Automatically compute r2 for several time series included in one dataset

Tags: r, time-series, lm

I would like to have the r² of linear models from several sets of data from one dataset. In my first  dataset, I have datetime and CO2 of all the sets. In my second dataset, I have the start time and end time of each set.
See below an illustration of my first dataset:

[image]

and an illustration of my second data set:
[image]

I would like to have for each raw of my second dataset the r² and a plot of the data (i.e. produce with the data from the first dataset).

Is it possible to do that with R and how?

Thanks a lot for your help and idea, and don't hesitate to ask questions, I am not sure I am clear.